# What's the sample rate for touchMove of Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone

When touch moves, touchMove is called by system. 
What's the interval between 2 moves?

Comment: May I ask what task you want to accomplish? The interval varies and is not time critical.

Comment: I think that depends on hardware or at least in software we, non-apple engineers have access to, but you could try. Use -[UITouch timeStamp] method.

Comment: @rjobidon I just want to know if I'll have performance bottleneck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fixed rate.  The information is interrupt driven by hardware, and handled by the OS.  If you write an app that simply logs the touchesMoved events, you can get a feel for it -- it is VERY fast.

If you're trying to draw, and running into a problem that finger-drawn circles come out jagged and angular, that's not a problem with touches-moved performance, that's a problem with drawing performance.  If this is the problem, you should ask another question about that -- there are several tricks, largely which revolve around separating gathering the touch data and drawing it into separate threads.

To see the speed of touches moved, create a new project, and have it do *NOTHING* except this:

(Code typed in web browser.  You may have to tweak it a little.)

```
static NSDate *touchReportDate = nil;
static touchMovedCount = 0;

- (void) logTouches
{
    NSDate *saveDate = touchReportDate;
    int saveCount = touchMovedCount;
    touchReportDate = nil;
    touchMovedCount = 0;
    NSTimeInterval secs = -[saveDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    [saveDate release];

    NSLog (@"%d touches in %0.2f seconds (%0.2f t/s)", saveCount, secs, (saveCount / secs));
}


- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *touches withEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{
    if (touchReportDate == nil)
        touchReportDate = [[NSDate date] retain];

    if ([touchReportDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < -1)  // report every second
    {
        [self logTouches]
    }
}


- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *touches) withEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{
    [self logTouches];
}

- (void) touchesCancelled: (NSSet *touches) withEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{
    [self touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Comment: The fastest sample rate on most devices is 60 Hz. It is easy for a user to draw a curve fast enough that connecting the samples with straight lines produces noticeable corners, even if you update the screen in well under 1/60th of a second.

Comment: Yes, if you're trying to draw curves, some sort of bezier or spline is probably better.  But the point is: collect your touch data separately from updating the screen, for which 10hz is typically plenty fast to look right.  (There are other techniques, like cache previous strokes, etc. but, again, that's a separate question & answer-set.)

Answer (score 3):

The maximum sample rate, according to [WWDC 2015 Session 233: Advanced Touch Input on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=233), is 60 Hz on all devices except (as of June 2015) the iPad Air 2, which samples at 120 Hz. Since the iPad Air 2 is the most recent device as of June 2015, future devices are likely to also have a 120 Hz sample rate.

Touch delivery is synchronized with screen refresh, which happens at 60 Hz on all devices. To take advantage of the iPad Air 2's higher sample rate, you must use `-[UIEvent coalescedTouchesForTouch:]`.

You will receive fewer than 60 (or 120) samples per second if the touch doesn't move, or if your app takes more than 1/60th of a second to respond to events.